# Member xxxx does not have permission to get company yyy

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I followed all process to get access_token on linkedin to get company API.

Query i fired:https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/company_id/updates?oauth2_access_token=generated access token&format=xml&event-type=status-update&count=5 and its giving error as:

4031437462043823R8LEL3EUI20Member yy does not have permission to get company xx

Note:User has been given admin rights on company page.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the process / steps followed ?

Comment: issue is resolved now.i chenge scope while requesting access token